# Iterate through three values stored in two places

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, hash

Edited some more. This is a tiny sample of a larger processing piece. My puzzle-solving logic needs to check a one of five attributes for one person against one of five attributes for his four neighbors. This example only shows three. In $hash1, the truth table, rows are people, columns are attributes. We're assuming managing the attributes- I will leave that info out as it's not central to this.

$hash1[2][2] is an 'edge', so it only needs to check against one neighbor, $hash[6][value1]

$hash1[5][2] is a 'middle', so it needs to check against two neighbors, $hash[3][value2] and $hash[9][value2]

The values in $hash1 are 9 for nil, 1 for true, 0 for false

so, in this case, "The man who wears red shirts lives next to the man who drives a Ford"

If we're checking to see if red shirt has been assigned, we need to look through keys 2, 5, 8. When the logic hits $hash1[5][2], and red shirt is 1, logic will check to see if one neighbor is nil and the other has a car which is not a Ford. If true, the nil car gets set to Ford.

```
 $hash1 = {1 => [9,9,9],  2 => [9,9,9],  3 => [9,9,9],
           4 => [9,9,9],  5 => [9,1,9],  6 => [9,9,9],
           7 => [9,9,9],  8 => [9,9,9],  9 => [9,9,1], 99 => [1,1,1]}

 $arry1 = [2,5,8]

 $hash2 = { 6 => 99, 3 => 9, 99 => 6}
```

(entry 99 is there to allow the code to use the same checking mechanism for edges as middles, because if it's the guy on the end, then he only has one neighbor, so if he has a red shirt, his neighbor definitely drives a Ford.)

I need it to loop three times total:

```
checking 2 and 6 , 99
then     5 and 3 , 9
then     8 and 99 , 6
```

I have everything working except for looping with the three values from two separate places- I am tinkering with this now-

```
    $arry1.zip($hash2).map(&:flatten).each |key,key2,key3|
```

Except what it is doing is merging them into this:

```
 <2, 6, 99> <5, 99, 6> <8>
```

For a longer array, same pattern- the first and last hash pairs come in and get paired with the first two array values, and the rest of the array values are unchanged.

Comment: This is hard to understand and harder to test, because `$hash` is incomplete. I suggest you edit to include a complete `$hash` (the shorter the better), shortened `name1` and `eman1`, and your desired output.  You also need to explain what `key3` is. Don't change what you have; just add "**Edit:** ..." at the end.

Comment: Hi- yes, sorry about that. The actual code is huge... I was not focusing on what I needed to ask- trying to explain too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is complete, you should be able to substitute:

```
val1.each do |key1|
  val2.each do |key2,key3|
```

with

```
val1.zip(val_2).map(&:flatten).each do |key1, key2, key3|
```

Additional note: When you're done with solving the problem, post it to codereview.stackexchange.com` so we can do sth with the smell. :)

Comment: Good one.  I couldn't figure out what was going on.

Comment: Hmm. I am getting an error:

    "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end", 

It is indicating the space immediately after the comma in ...|key1,

Comment: oh, man! I tried that and it didn't work, but that was amidst ten other things I was trying- thank you! Oh... but it's not working. It's merging the first and last Hash values with the first two array values, and leaving the rest of the array values with no partners. So instead of [a1, h1, h2,] [a2, h3, h4, ][a3, h5, h6]... I am getting [a1, h1, h2,][a2, h9, h10][a3][a4][a5]

Comment: That would suggest that your array has more elements than has you're zipping it with.

Comment: Your hash has duplicate keys - it is not allowed. Only last value will be present.

Comment: Store it as an array `[[99, 3], [-7,3], [-7,3], [-7,3], [-7,99]]`

Comment: ...or as `{ 99 => [3], -7 => [3, 3, 3, 99] }`.

Comment: Awesome! So working now. Thanks so much! Also, I am on to another issue with my logic... posted a ton of the actual code... however it looks like I have an X/Y problem now. :D